# Is it possible to detect if there is an HDMI device connected using C#?

Tags: c#

Just like the title says, I am wanting to know if it is possible to determine if an HDMI device is connected using C#.

Comment: Sure it is. If nothing else you can download an application that does this, and execute it from C# :) You can probably do this using some (unreliable) registry keys, or (somewhat reliable) by marshalling unmanaged drivers or other such apis. Also maybe look at DirectX api's for this at a guess.

Comment: With P/Invoke, there is a way, but only from Vista (according to MSDN) or Win7 on (according to WinGDI.h target version defines): using WDK / GDI; QueryDisplayConfig gives you DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO, that contains DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_TARGET_INFO and that finally a value from DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY. Since this is quite complex and native, I don't think that's the answer you're looking for, but it shows that it's possible...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came up with **powershell** solution:

```
$HDMI_Monitors = 0;
$wmiobject = (get-wmiobject -namespace root\WMI -computername localhost -Query "Select * from WmiMonitorConnectionParams")
foreach ($letter in $wmiobject)
{
    if($letter["VideoOutputTechnology"] -eq 5) #HDMI cable have value of 5 
    {
        HDMI_Monitors += 1;
    }
}
Write-Host "Number of connected HDMI cables : $HDMI_Monitors"
```

This will list no. of connected **HDMI cables**.
It crawls all displays and count only **HDMI** from **VideoOutputTechnology**. HDMI always have 5 value.
Credits:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58545201/11390822)
**Update:1 c# code:**

```cs
int HDMI_Monitors = 0;
ManagementClass mClass = new ManagementClass(@"\\localhost\ROOT\WMI:WmiMonitorConnectionParams");
foreach (ManagementObject mObject in mClass.GetInstances())
{
    if (mObject["VideoOutputTechnology"].Equals(5)) //Because D3DKMDT_VOT_HDMI = 5
    {
        HDMI_Monitors += 1;
    }
}
    Console.WriteLine("Number of connected HDMI cables : " + HDMI_Monitors.ToString());
```

Reason:**WmiMonitorConnectionParams** array returns number of external displays and their info including **VideoOutputTechnology**,**InstanceName**,**Active**. We need **VideoOutputTechnology** to check whether value is 5 or not and then count it. **D3DKMDT_VOT_HDMI=5** Credits:[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/d3dkmdt/ne-d3dkmdt-_d3dkmdt_video_output_technology) & [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601012/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-there-is-an-hdmi-device-connected-using-c/64739380#comment114494201_64739380) & [wutils.com.](https://wutils.com/wmi/root/wmi/wmimonitorconnectionparams/cs-samples.html).

**Update:2 vbscript code:**

```vb
Dim HDMI_Monitors 
HDMI_Monitors = 0
For Each Instance In GetObject("WINMGMTS:\\localhost\ROOT\WMI").InstancesOf("WmiMonitorConnectionParams", 1) 
    If Instance.VideoOutputTechnology = 5 Then 
        HDMI_Monitors =  + 1
    End if
Next 
Wscript.Echo "No. of connected HDMI cables :" & HDMI_Monitors
```

Same ideology as explained in c# code. Just for **visual basic** ,**vbscript**,**VBA**,**vbs** etc. Credits: [wutils.com](https://wutils.com/wmi/root/wmi/wmimonitorconnectionparams/vbscript-samples.html#InstancesOf).

**Update: 3 C++ code**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main()
{
    int HDMI_Monitors  = 0;
    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;
    IEnumWbemClassObject *pEnumerator = NULL;
    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;
    HRESULT hres = NULL;
    
    hres = CoInitializeEx (0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    hres = CoInitializeSecurity (NULL, -1,NULL,NULL,RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,NULL,EOAC_NONE,NULL);
    hres = CoCreateInstance (CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) & pLoc);
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer (_bstr_t (L"\\\\localhost\\root\\WMI"),NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0,0,&pSvc);
    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket (pSvc,RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,NULL,RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,NULL,EOAC_NONE);
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery (L"WQL", L"SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorConnectionParams",WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &pEnumerator);
    
        while (pEnumerator)
        {
            HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next (WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
            if (0 == uReturn || FAILED (hr))
            {
              break;
            }
            
            VARIANT vtProp;
            hr = pclsObj->Get (L"VideoOutputTechnology", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0); 
            if(vtProp.uintVal == 5)
            {
                HDMI_Monitors+=1;
            }
            VariantClear (&vtProp);
            pclsObj->Release ();
            pclsObj = NULL; 
        }
        
        std::cout << "Number of connected HDMI cables : " << HDMI_Monitors;
        return 0;           
}
```

Credits: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10090666/11390822)

Comment: This does only print the number of items returned by the query. One could inspect the `D3DKMDT_VOT_HDMI` property of the result to get the `VideoOutputTechnology` for each element to see if there is a device connected through HDMI though.

Comment: This is well tested. Number of items only return if devices are connected.

Comment: Connect and disconnect HDMI to see output difference.

Comment: Of course there is only a number if there are any devices. But i still get two devices (= `Array.Length == 2`) when i have one device connected through `DVI` and one through `DP`. So the raw query does not help me identify `HDMI` devices. The number of `HDMI` devices can only be determined if you look at the `VideoOutputTechnology` property and not by looking at the number of array elements, unless i get the core of your answer wrong(?).

Comment: Right. So which thing will make it clear that its `HDMI` using `VideoOutputTechnology` property ?

Comment: It is present even no cable is present. for me its number `2147483648`.

Comment: `D3DKMDT_VOT_HDMI` has the value `5`. `-2147483648` is `D3DKMDT_VOT_INTERNAL`. You can look up the values in the `d3dkmdt.h` header.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single API (like DirectX) that would allow you to query for that directly.  You'd probably need to write some custom routines for ATI/NVidia/etc. cards for that and wrap it into your own mini-API.

Comment: Doesn't DxDiag tell you this stuff though? I would wonder if you could use DirectX to pull the info DxDiag does and if that would tell you. Maybe not, this isn't my realm of expertise at all..

Comment: Looking at DxDiag now and I see "plug and play monitor," but no indication of the type of interface (VGA/HDMI/DVI).  It might be possible with low-level DirectX calls but I doubt it.

Comment: Since MS changed their display driver model for Vista and for Win7, it **is** possible using the WDK / GDI since Win7. I wrote a comment to the question with the links.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense you couldn't possibly. They could have a DVI->HDMI connector plugged in so it is plugged in as HDMI but the machine only knows it as DVI, or a hand full of other connection types that can be be dongled (teehee) to HDMI.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible. you can use the device manager to find out whether a HDMI cable is attached. I had worked on a code to find whether USB is connected and also whether a monitor is connected or not. if u notice any change in the device manager when the HDMI cable is plugged in, you can use that to detect HDMI