# How can I know which HDMI port is plugged in?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, registry, wmi

I have a computer with a dual hdmi output. I would like to detect which one is plugged in when I connect a monitor to either to one of them.

It can be either with the help of registry, powershell or C# code, or anything. As long as it's not C++.

I've tried various wmi methods. Searched the registry for anything that would specify a hdmi port. But found nothing so far.

This stackoverflow answer ([Detect/identify the port (HDMI, other) the monitor is connected to in Windows 7/8/10 Win32 C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712915/detect-identify-the-port-hdmi-other-the-monitor-is-connected-to-in-windows-7)) is the only one I found regarding my need, but I can't handle c++ so from now on I'm stuck.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Use P/Invoke then.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this will work, but to use that WMI class in say, PowerShell, you should be able to do 

    get-ciminstance -namespace root/wmi -classname WmiMonitorConnectionParams

I think it will only tell you that you are using a HDMI port, but not which HDMI port. Maybe run it, switch ports, and run it again to see what changes- my machine only has the single HDMI port here.

Comment: @Mark Already tried that, nothing pops up that could identify a specific port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in powershell.

```
$objWMi = get-wmiobject -namespace root\WMI -computername localhost -Query "Select * from WmiMonitorConnectionParams"

foreach ($obj in $objWmi)
{
    write-host "Active:" $obj.Active
    write-host "InstanceName:" $obj.InstanceName
    write-host "VideoOutputTechnology:" $obj.VideoOutputTechnology
    write-host
    write-host "########"
    write-host
}
```

The WmiMonitorConnectionParams class has VideoOutputTechnology property which returns the following:

```
    typedef enum _D3DKMDT_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY { 
  D3DKMDT_VOT_UNINITIALIZED         = -2,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_OTHER                 = -1,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_HD15                  = 0,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_SVIDEO                = 1,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_COMPOSITE_VIDEO       = 2,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_COMPONENT_VIDEO       = 3,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_DVI                   = 4,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_HDMI                  = 5,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_LVDS                  = 6,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_D_JPN                 = 8,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_SDI                   = 9,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_DISPLAYPORT_EXTERNAL  = 10,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_DISPLAYPORT_EMBEDDED  = 11,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_UDI_EXTERNAL          = 12,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_UDI_EMBEDDED          = 13,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_SDTVDONGLE            = 14,
#if (DXGKDDI_INTERFACE_VERSION >= DXGKDDI_INTERFACE_VERSION_WDDM1_3_M1)
  D3DKMDT_VOT_MIRACAST              = 15,
#endif 
  D3DKMDT_VOT_INTERNAL              = 0x80000000,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_SVIDEO_4PIN           = D3DKMDT_VOT_SVIDEO,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_SVIDEO_7PIN           = D3DKMDT_VOT_SVIDEO,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_RF                    = D3DKMDT_VOT_COMPOSITE_VIDEO,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_RCA_3COMPONENT        = D3DKMDT_VOT_COMPONENT_VIDEO,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_BNC                   = D3DKMDT_VOT_COMPONENT_VIDEO
} D3DKMDT_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY;
```